# Get worldpay payment response on a PHP website

Tags: php, worldpay

I am integrating Worldpay payment gateway to PHP ecommerce website using HTML redirect method. Right now I am able to get a correct response if the transaction was success or failure through Worldpay's resultC and resultY html files through GET method.

Here is ResultY.html code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<website_url>/response.php?transId=
<WPDISPLAY> ITEM=transId>&cartId=<WPDISPLAY ITEM=cartId>&transStatus=<WPDISPLAY ITEM=transStatus>"
```

But my question is this method safe as it involves transactions and based on the result I get from this url I have to update my database for that particular order along with displaying user about his transaction status.

If any one has a more better way please let me know. Thanks.